# Count certain chemical reaction in string of data

Tags: r, string, sapply, strsplit

What is the most effective way to count e.g. methylations (Differences by CH2) in a string of molecular formulas. Consider inside a string of 100 different molecular formulas I have some formulas like C6H14O3 and C5H12O3 and C4H10O3. The first one and the second differ by CH2, the second and the third differ by CH2 so I have 2 methylations in this string. When the string is very large this becomes more complex. So I want to count how many molecular formulas differ by just one CH2 in the string.

Consider I have :

```
DT<- data.frame(formula=c("C6H12O7S1","C6H10O8S1","C7H4O2N4","C8H12O5S1","C8H16O5S1","C8H12O3N2","C8H14O4S1","C9H7O3N1S1","C9H11O6N1S1","C9H9O6N1S1","C9H12O5S1","C9H18O5S1","C9H14O5","C9H20O5S1","C9H9O4N1S1","C9H9O5N1S1","C9H14O6","C10H11O5N1S1","C10H14O6","C10H16O6S1","C10H17O5N1","C10H20O7S1","C10H14O4","C10H12O7N2","C10H16O6","C10H14O6N2","C10H7O4N1S1","C10H18O6S1","C10H16O5","C10H13O6N1S1","C10H18O7S1","C11H18O6S1","C11H15O6N1","C11H22O7S1","C11H16O6S1","C11H16O6","C11H18O6"))
```

I want to count how many CH2 differences like explained above are in this string.

Does somebody now an easy way to do this especially for very large strings?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you comparing every string to every other string or just 1st-to-2nd, 2nd-to-3rd etc?

Comment: I haven't programmed in R, but a regex to split each formula into its element and number will probably be the easiest way to go, using environments to create a hash lookup. something like `regmatches(regexpr("C\d+H\d+", your_var_here, perl=TRUE), your_var_here)` should get you the `CxHy` combos

Comment: @thelatemail I want to compare every string to every other string.

Comment: You could even do something like `strsplit(as.character(DT$formula[1:3]), "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl=TRUE)` as a starting point to split all nums and characters into separate chunks.

Comment: Your backbone is always the same, and can only differ by methylations and nothing else? For example, acetylations are not possible, right?

Comment: There might be acetylations in the datastring but I want to count only the methylations.Later on I want to change the methylation criterion to other like e.g. acetylations and search for that sum and so on. But the first step are methylations for a examplatory solution.

Comment: so basically, you want to extract the second character in all of the strings and compare that value to all the values and find how many values are off by one to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses thelatemail's suggestion as starting point to split the strings:

Reproduce the original dataset (setting stringsAsFactors to F)

```
DT <- data.frame(formula=c("C6H12O7S1","C6H10O8S1","C7H4O2N4","C8H12O5S1","C8H16O5S1",
                          "C8H12O3N2","C8H14O4S1","C9H7O3N1S1","C9H11O6N1S1","C9H9O6N1S1",
                          "C9H12O5S1","C9H18O5S1","C9H14O5","C9H20O5S1","C9H9O4N1S1",
                          "C9H9O5N1S1","C9H14O6","C10H11O5N1S1","C10H14O6","C10H16O6S1",
                          "C10H17O5N1","C10H20O7S1","C10H14O4","C10H12O7N2","C10H16O6",
                          "C10H14O6N2","C10H7O4N1S1","C10H18O6S1","C10H16O5","C10H13O6N1S1",
                          "C10H18O7S1","C11H18O6S1","C11H15O6N1","C11H22O7S1","C11H16O6S1","C11H16O6",
                          "C11H18O6"), stringsAsFactors = F) %>% arrange(formula)

> head(DT)
       formula
1 C10H11O5N1S1
2   C10H12O7N2
3 C10H13O6N1S1
4     C10H14O4
5     C10H14O6
6   C10H14O6N2
```

Expand columns such that there's one column to count each element (absent ones are counted as 0)

```
DT2 <- strsplit(DT$formula, "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl=TRUE) %>%
  lapply(function(x){structure(list(formula = rep(paste0(x, collapse = ""), length(x)/2),
                                    element = x[seq(from = 1, to = length(x), by = 2)],
                                    count = as.integer(x[seq(from = 2, to = length(x), by = 2)])),
                               .Names = c("formula", "element", "count"),
                               row.names = c(NA, -length(x)/2), 
                               class = "data.frame")}) %>%
  data.table::rbindlist() %>% 
  spread(element, count, fill = 0)

>head(DT2)
        formula  C  H N O S
1: C10H11O5N1S1 10 11 1 5 1
2:   C10H12O7N2 10 12 2 7 0
3: C10H13O6N1S1 10 13 1 6 1
4:     C10H14O4 10 14 0 4 0
5:     C10H14O6 10 14 0 6 0
6:   C10H14O6N2 10 14 2 6 0
```

Obtain list of all possible pairwise combinations & expand the dataset

```
pairwise.combos <- combn(nrow(DT2), m = 2)

DT3 <- rbind(DT2[pairwise.combos[1,],],
             DT2[pairwise.combos[2,],])
DT3$pair <- rep(seq.int(dim(pairwise.combos)[2]),2)

> head(DT3)
        formula  C  H N O S pair
1: C10H11O5N1S1 10 11 1 5 1    1
2: C10H11O5N1S1 10 11 1 5 1    2
3: C10H11O5N1S1 10 11 1 5 1    3
4: C10H11O5N1S1 10 11 1 5 1    4
5: C10H11O5N1S1 10 11 1 5 1    5
6: C10H11O5N1S1 10 11 1 5 1    6
```

**Edit** for the final step based on OP's clarification that a pair of formulae should only differ by CH2, & counts for other elements should be the same.

Check whether each pair is different by CH2 (this step can be modified to check for other differences)

```
DT4 <- DT3 %>% group_by(pair) %>%
  arrange(C, H) %>%
  summarise(CH2.diff = (diff(C) == 1) && (diff(H) == 2) && 
              (diff(N) == 0) & (diff(O) == 0) & (diff(S) == 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(CH2.diff == 1) %>% select(pair)
DT4 <- right_join(DT3, DT4)

# total count of CH2 in pairwise comparisons
> length(unique(DT4$pair))
[1] 9

# check which pairs differ by CH2
> head(DT4)
       formula  C  H N O S pair
1 C10H11O5N1S1 10 11 1 5 1   35
2   C9H9O5N1S1  9  9 1 5 1   35
3 C10H13O6N1S1 10 13 1 6 1   96
4  C9H11O6N1S1  9 11 1 6 1   96
5     C10H14O6 10 14 0 6 0  149
6     C11H16O6 11 16 0 6 0  149
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers. This is great you made my day! One question: could this pairwise.combos become problematic when my vector of strings is very long (above 1000) or is this just a question of working memory.

Comment: One thing: This code looks for CH2 differences but with methylation I mean that the rest of the molecule has to stay the same, so your pair 34 is wrong because it has less oxygen than its pair counterpart. pair 35 is correct, pair 36 again has one more oxygen and is not correct. I only want to count that ones that differ by CH2 only but are equal in everything else. How could I acomplish that? many thanks.

Comment: @JmO Thanks for the clarification. I've modified the last part of my solution to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try this. probably not the most effective, but it should work:

```
# extract only the second value, aka the number of carbons
DT$formula <- substr(DT$formula, 2, 2)

# counter for matches off by 1
counter <- 0

# for loop that counts all matches
for (i in 1:nrow(DT))
{
  for (j in 1:nrow(DT))
  {
      # if entries' values are off by 1
      if (i != j && ((DT[j, 1] + 1 == DT[i, 1]) || (DT[j, 1] - 1 == DT[i, 1])))
      {
          counter <- counter + 1
      }
   }
}

# so you don't count the pair twice
counter <- counter/2
```